# SQL top 10 results in nested query

Tags: sql, nested

hope someone can help me produce a nested query.  Does not have to be efficient, just simple to follow.

I am looking to "Find the top 10 albums that have the greatest number of played tracks"

I have the following tables:
 **Album** which has GRid and Title
 **AlbumTrack** which has GRid and ISRC
 **Track** which has ISRC and PlayCount

Ive currently got:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Album.Title
FROM Album
WHERE Grid IN

(SELECT AlbumTrack.GRid 
FROM AlbumTrack
WHERE ISRC IN

(SELECT Track,ISRC
FROM TRACK
WHERE Track.ISRC = SUM(Track.PlayCount)
ORDER BY Track.PlayCount));
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Add sample data and expected output for better answer

Comment: You need to top 10 the tracks, not the albums.

Comment: add rdbms tag also

Comment: I am trying to get the top 10 album which have the most played tracks.  A track can be on multiple albums. Likewise a track could not feature on the album.  Therefore the top album may not have any of the top 10 tracks on it.

Comment: Check my solution for exact answer @SarahPainter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query :

```
 SELECT TOP 10 Album.Title FROM Album
    JOIN AlbumTrack ON Album.Grid = AlbumTrack.GRid
    JOIN (SELECT Sum(PlayCount) as NumberOfPlay , ISRC  TRACK
    GROUP BY AlbumTrack.ISRC
    ) as Track ON AlbumTrack.ISRC = Track.ISRC
    ORDER BY Track.NumberOfPlay
```

Comment: What if more than one Album.Title is having same value. Check in this scenario if 100 is present 10 times then you will only get 100 as result not top 10 @SarahPainter

Answer (score 1):

**Using Join**

```
SELECT Title 
FROM (
        SELECT Album.Title,
               DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PlayCount) AS RN
        FROM Album 
        INNER JOIN AlbumTrack
        ON Album.Grid = AlbumTrack.Grid
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT ISRC, SUM(PlayCount) AS PlayCount
            FROM TRACK
            GROUP BY ISRC
        )AS TRACK
        ON AlbumTrack.ISRC=TRACK.ISRC
    ) AS T
WHERE RN<=10
```

Comment: Thank you, yes it helps.

Comment: Welcome If you got your answer please Accept and upvote @SarahPainter